# Weak existence for modified Tanaka SDE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Tanaka's theorem ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula)) implies that $X_t = |B_t|$ is a weak solution to the SDE

$dX_t = dW_t + dL_t^0(X_t)$,

where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion and $L_t^0(X_t)$ is the local time of $X_t$ at $0$.  I have two related questions:

1. Does there exist a (weak) solution to the SDE

$dX_t = dW_t + 2 dL_t^0(X_t)$

where again $L_t^0(X_t)$ is the local time of $X_t$ at $0$?

2. What about the SDE

$dX_t = \sqrt{X_t}dW_t + 2 dL_t^1(X_t)$,

where $L_t^1(X_t)$ is the local time of $X_t$ at $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first see ch 6 prob 2.24 of Revuz & Yor

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the paper of Harrison-Shepp which describes the resulting process: [On skew Brownian motion](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~shepp/publications/52.pdf).